# Evaluating escaped string literals in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider the following code snippet:

```
var a = '\\555';
var b = '\555';
console.log(a, b); // outputs \555 -5
```

So the value of `a` has an escaped back-slash and `b` has escaped 55 which is the octal equivalent of the Unicode code-point of the "minus" or "dash" and the trailing `5` is concatenated to the `-` resulting in `-5`.

Now I want to the best way to "evaluate/decode" the value of `a` in such a way that it is equal to the value of `b`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you use regex ?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. `a` and `b` are two different values, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Khang Sorry if the question was not clear. All I'm trying to do is "decode" the value of `a` so that `decode(a) === b` becomes `true`. Hope its clear now.

Comment: @Greggz Yes, I can. But parsing the string as per the Javascript specs would be very taxing. Nevertheless, what solution do you suggest?

Comment: You will need to use Regex to detect and replace the octal sequence of `a` with an equivalent character

Comment: Do you need to be able to replace things like '\\n' as well or just (deprecated) octal escapes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval` can do this (assuming it's a valid string and contains no other escapes and no quotes):

```
var a = '\\555';
console.log(eval('"' + a '"'));
```

but indeed an explicit decode function is a better idea:

```
function decodeOctEscapes(x) {
    return x.replace(/\\([0-7]{2})/g, (_, v) => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(v, 8)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways except Regex, but none of them is ideal:

```
var a1 = '\\555';
// unsafe: only for trusted values
var a2 = eval('"' + a1 + '"');

var b1 = '\555';
// ES6 raw string; cannot be created on runtime
var b2 = String.raw`\555`;

console.log(a1===b2) // true
console.log(a2===b1) // true
```